# Webservice end point url not connecting

Tags: web-services, soapui

I am trying to connect to a remote web service endpoint by soap ui and keep getting connection refused error. A co worker can connect just fine. As a means of troubleshooting the issue, I pasted the http end point url on IE and it gave me 'Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage' error. Does this mean there is anything wrong with my internet settings?

The web service vendor is unable to help because it is working from a co worker's machine.

Comment: Do you have a firewall on your machine?

Comment: Please post this as an answer. I configured microsoft firewall client and the error did not come.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you are being caught out by a firewall, either on your machine or on a network segment between your machine and the server you are accessing.

Given that your colleague works, the first place to look would be your machines firewall settings.